# Как изменять значения в ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview

у меня есть ListView в который я вставляю значения через adapter значения беру из ArayList. Вот сама установка адаптера.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, pizzaNames, R.layout.adapter_backet, from, to);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

В коде я изменяю переменные, но при этом на экране изменения появляются только после перезапуска активности т.к. адаптер устанавливается в методе onCreat. Так вот вопрос, как сделать так что бы при нажатии кнопки + или - изменялось значения сразу на экране.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код активности где устанавливается адаптер:

```
public class BasketPage extends Activity {
        List<Map<String, String>> pizzaNames = new ArrayList<>();

        public String name;
        public String phoneNumber;
        public String street;
        public String home;
        public String porch;
        public String level;
        public String apprt;
        public String comment;
        public boolean b;

        WorkBD workBD;
        MainActivity mainActivity;

    public void culculateFprice(){
        TextView FinalBuy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buyText);
        int Pprice = MainActivity.pepperoni.getFinalPrice();
        int Cprice = MainActivity.calzone.getFinalPrice();
        int QCprice = MainActivity.quattrostagioni.getFinalPrice();
        int QFprice = MainActivity.quattroformaggi.getFinalPrice();
        int Mprice = MainActivity.mexican.getFinalPrice();
        int FinalPrice = Pprice + Cprice + QCprice + QFprice + Mprice;
        FinalBuy.setText("Стоимось вашего заказа: " + FinalPrice + " руб.");
    }



        public void creator() {
            System.out.println(MainActivity.pepperoni.getCount());
            if (MainActivity.pepperoni.getCount() != 0) {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("text1", "Пепперони ");
                map.put("text2", MainActivity.pepperoni.getCount() + " шт.");
                pizzaNames.add(map);
            }
            if (MainActivity.calzone.getCount() != 0) {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("text1", "Кальцоне ");
                map.put("text2", MainActivity.calzone.getCount() + " шт.");
                pizzaNames.add(map);
            }
            if (MainActivity.quattrostagioni.getCount() != 0) {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("text1", "Четыре сезона ");
                map.put("text2", MainActivity.quattrostagioni.getCount() + " шт.");
                pizzaNames.add(map);
            }
            if (MainActivity.quattroformaggi.getCount() != 0) {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("text1", "Четыре сыра ");
                map.put("text2", MainActivity.quattroformaggi.getCount() + " шт.");
                pizzaNames.add(map);
            }

            if (MainActivity.mexican.getCount() != 0) {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("text1", "Мексиканская ");
                map.put("text2", MainActivity.mexican.getCount() + " шт.");
                pizzaNames.add(map);
            }
        }

        @Override

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.bascket_page);
            mainActivity= new MainActivity();
            creator();
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.titles);
            String [] from = {"text1" , "text2"};
            int [] to = {R.id.textok1 , R.id.textok2};
            ListAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, pizzaNames, R.layout.adapter_backet, from, to);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            culculateFprice();
            workBD = new WorkBD(this);
        }

...
}
```

код Castom adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View inflatedLayout = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        Button plus = inflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.plus);
        Button minus = inflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.minus);
        final ArrayList <String> Pizzas = new ArrayList<>();
        if(MainActivity.pepperoni.getCount() != 0)
            Pizzas.add("pizza1");
        if(MainActivity.calzone.getCount() != 0)
            Pizzas.add("pizza2");
        if(MainActivity.quattrostagioni.getCount() != 0)
            Pizzas.add("pizza3");
        if(MainActivity.quattroformaggi.getCount() != 0)
            Pizzas.add("pizza4");
        if(MainActivity.mexican.getCount() != 0)
            Pizzas.add("pizza5");

        plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Button was clicked for list item " + position);
                boolean b = true;
                int i = 0;
                while(b){
                    i++;
                    String j = "pizza" + i;
                    if(j.equals(Pizzas.get(position))){

                        b = false;

                        if(i == 1) {
                            int y = MainActivity.pepperoni.getCount();
                            MainActivity.pepperoni.setCount(y+1);
                        }

                        if(i == 2) {
                            int y = MainActivity.calzone.getCount();
                            MainActivity.calzone.setCount(y + 1);
                        }

                        if(i == 3) {
                            int y = MainActivity.quattrostagioni.getCount();
                            MainActivity.quattrostagioni.setCount(y + 1);
                        }

                        if(i == 4) {
                            int y = MainActivity.quattroformaggi.getCount();
                            MainActivity.quattroformaggi.setCount(y + 1);
                        }

                        if (i == 5) {
                            int y = MainActivity.mexican.getCount();
                            MainActivity.mexican.setCount(y + 1);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        });



        minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Button was clicked for list item " + position);
                boolean b = true;
                int i = 0;
                while(b){
                    i++;
                    String j = "pizza" + i;
                    if(j.equals(Pizzas.get(position))){

                        b = false;

                        if(i == 1) {
                            int y = MainActivity.pepperoni.getCount();
                            MainActivity.pepperoni.setCount(y - 1);
                        }

                        if(i == 2) {
                            int y = MainActivity.calzone.getCount();
                            MainActivity.calzone.setCount(y - 1);
                        }

                        if(i == 3) {
                            int y = MainActivity.quattrostagioni.getCount();
                            MainActivity.quattrostagioni.setCount(y - 1);
                        }

                        if(i == 4) {
                            int y = MainActivity.quattroformaggi.getCount();
                            MainActivity.quattroformaggi.setCount(y - 1);
                        }

                        if (i == 5) {
                            int y = MainActivity.mexican.getCount();
                            MainActivity.mexican.setCount(y - 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return inflatedLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: сетьте адаптер снова, с новыми данными

Comment: Можно подробнее как это делать? Просто когда я заново делаю адаптер , то он  идет под предыдущим. Как удалять прошлый?

Comment: приложите код изменения данных который вы хотите отображать в списке

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то вот:                                                  
      int y = MainActivity.calzone.getCount();
      MainActivity.calzone.setCount(y + 1);

Comment: а в адаптер они как передаются? кнопки у вас в адаптере я так понимаю? как вы обрабатываете нажатия на эти кнопки? я про этот код спрашивал)

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: то есть вы хотите чтобы при нажатии на + кол-во например с 3 увеличивалось на 4?

Comment: да, а при нажатии "-" уменьшалось на 1.

Comment: можно сделать функцию, в вашей активности которая очищать адаптер и заполнять новыми данными, делайте так же как и сетите переменную в активности, и в функцию для очистки добавьте `listView.setAdapter(null);` и дальше снова заполняйте с новыми данными

Comment: Спасибо, но не могли бы вы уточнить где вызывать эту функцию.Я создал функцию, но откуда её вызывать?

Comment: там где вы меняете значения кол-ва, в адаптере

Comment: Когда я её оттуда вызываю выходит ошибка что non-static метод не может быть вызван из статичного контекста. И я никак не могу исправить эту ошибку.

Comment: а вы пробовали метод статическим сделать? вообще listview не предназначен для таких сложных манипуляций, проще использовать recyclerView

Comment: Да пробовал, но там другие ошибки выходят. Я если честно никогда не работал с RecyclerView, поэтому более предпочтительно использовать ListView. Но если через лист вью никак то придется делать через recyclerView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать метод

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Но я бы вам вообще рекомендовал отказаться от ListView в пользу RecyclrRView. В нынешних реалиях никто не использует ListView. RecyclerView быстрее, он реализует паттерн ViewHolder, что дает более быструю подгрузку данных за счет переиспользования ячеек. Он более гибок и в нем легче работать с анимациями кликами. И вообще это в целом более современное решение, в котором нет тех проблем которыми обладает ListView.

Помимо notifyDataSetChanged() в RecyclerView можно обновлять данные выборочно (только те которые изменились, а не весь список) с помощью DiffUtils.

[Рекомендую для чтения](https://ziginsider.github.io/What_is_the_difference_between_ListView_and_RecyclerView/)

Comment: Хм странно, но у меня почему-то не изменяется ListView после вызова notifyDataSetChanged().